# jQuery find my page scroll value (offset - position)

Tags: jquery, scroll, position, offset

i've a problem with a lightbox i've done in Safari and FF.

If i open my lightbox when the page is scrolled down and then I close the lightbox the page scroll to top istantly... i really don't understand why.

there is a way to get the current page scrolling so i can set it when i close the lightbox to avoid the scroll top?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The anchor tag used in the close action probably looks similar to this:

```
<a href="#"></a>
```

And that empty hashtag is sending you back to the top of the page.  You'll know this is true if your browser's URL suddenly has a `#` at the end of it.

To stop it, you need to stop the default behavior of the anchor, either by returning false on click, or by using something like jQuery's [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method (preferred).

Comment: the problem is that I use jquery address in my lightbox...so when i close my lightbox, my Url is something like this  page.html#  Any ideas how can i remove the hash??

Answer (score 0):

i believe you're triggering the anchor link.

Make sure to return false on your close function.